# What regular expression do I use for replacing numbers with leading zeros?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a bunch of strings like this:

```
my $string1 = "xg0000";
my $string2 = "fx0015";
```

What do I do to increase the number in the string by 1 but also maintain the leading zeros to keep the length of the string the same.

I tried this:

```
$string =~ s/(\d+)/0 x length(int($1)) . ($1+1)/e;
```

It doesn't seem to work on all numbers. Is regex what I'm supposet to use to do this or is there a better way?

Comment: What is supposed to happen on "xg9999" plus one?

Comment: Well this was just an example (a poor one). My real strings start from 00 and there's never more than 50 increments so I don't have to worry about it going to 99 and overflowing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about a little perl magic? The `++` operator will work even on strings, and `0000` will magically turn into `0001`.

Now, we can't modify `$1` since it is readonly, but we can use an intermediate variable.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $string = "xg0000"; 
$string =~ s/(\d+)/my $x=$1; ++$x/e;
```

Update:

I didn't think of this before, but it actually works without a regex:

```
C:\perl>perl -we "$str = 'xg0000'; print ++$str;"
xg0001
```

Still does not solve the problem DavidO pointed out, with `9999`. You would have to decide what to do with those numbers. Perl has a rather interesting solution for it:

```
C:\perl>perl -we "$str = 'xg9999'; print ++$str;"
xh0000
```

Comment: Oh, cool. I didn't know you could declare a variable in there like that.

Comment: If you think that is cool, you obviously haven't seen the update to my question yet. ;)

Comment: Hm. That doesn't seem to work if the string is say, 'abc1xg0002' but works with regex. I should've mentioned in the original question that it can have numbers and characters too before the xg, but just the last series of numbers are what I'm interested in incrementing.

Comment: @ces I guess it is magical in more ways than one. But no, it doesn't just look for numbers, it can also inc a string such as 'xa'.

Comment: See my post [Be careful with Unicode character ranges](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/blog/1220) for details on this magic.

Comment: @cespinoza: no; when it starts with a digit (0-9), it is treated as just a number; anything after the first digits is discarded (with a warning if there was non-whitespace).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with [sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) too, and use the length you compute from the number of digits that you capture:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "xg00000";

foreach ( 0 .. 9 ) {
    $string =~ s/([0-9]+)\z/
        my $l = length $1;
        sprintf "%0${l}d", $1 + 1;
        /e; 
    print "$string\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a really bad task to solve with a regexp. Increasing a number can change an unlimited number of digits, and can in fact also change the number of non-zero digits! Unless you have sworn an oath to use only regexes for  a year, use regex to extract the number and then `sprintf "%06d" $x+1` to regenerate the new number with the desired width.